# How to update global variable (associative array) after jQuery Ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How to update global variable (associative array) after jQuery Ajax call?

```
var languageCode = {};
$.ajax({
  url: 'languages/en.xml',
  success: function(xml) {
    $(xml).find('string').each(function() {
      languageCode[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).text();
      console.log(languageCode.IDSA_HI_THERE);  // This works
    });
    console.log(languageCode);
  }
});
console.log(languageCode.IDSA_HI_THERE); // This doesn't work because this gets called before the ajax request. How to make this work?
```

Comment: add `async:false` option in your ajax call

Comment: `$.ajax` is a async call. So last line from your code will never work as you wanted. Only thing you can do it to make it work is modify the ajax call to run it synchronously instead of async by introducing `async: false` option within `$.ajax` settings.

Comment: it's working. thanks